# R: how can I calculate the percentages a variable takes on a certain value by group?

Tags: r, dplyr, group-by, percentage

So I'm trying to get r to report the share of a certain variable taking on a specific value in a group.
For example: Let`s consider a dataset which consists of groups 1,2 and 3. Now I would like to know the percentage a Variable1 takes on the value 500 in group 1,2 and 3 and incorporate this as a new vaiable.
Is there a convenient way to get to a solution?
So it should look something like this:

```
df
Group  Var1   Var1_perc
1       0      50
1       400    50
1       500    50
1       500    50
```

and so on for the other groups

Comment: How do you obtain 50??

Comment: Can you share reproducible example ? May be using dput?

Answer (score 1):

I would use `tidyverse` to do this

Calculate how often a variable takes on a certain value in a group

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
 group_by(Group,Var1) %>% 
 summarise(count = n())
```

To calculate the percentage in a group:

```
df %>% 
  left_join(df %>% 
               group_by(grp) %>% 
               summarise(n = n()), by = "grp" ) %>%
  group_by(grp,value) %>%
  summarise(percentage = n()/n)
```

The whole `left_join` stuff is to calculate how often a group appears in the table. I couldn't think of a better one rn.

Comment: I keep getting this: Error: `n()` must only be used inside dplyr verbs.

Comment: try `dplyr::summarise()`

Comment: Just FYI it looks like the tidyverse-related functions you've used are all from dplyr, which means you can decrease overhead by just loading that instead of all the tidyverse libraries

Comment: Yes you are totally right, it's probably a habit to load `tidyverse`. I guess the error @philipp.kn_98 gets is because of some library conflicts, e.g. loading `plyr` on top of `dplyr` or `tidyverse`